# Is there a PyPi source download link that always points to the lastest version?

Tags: python, pypi

Say my latest version of a package is on PyPi and the source can be downloaded with this url:

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pydy/pydy-0.3.1.tar.gz

I'd really like to have a url that looks like:

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pydy/pydy-latest.tar.gz

which will always redirect to the latest version, in this case 0.3.1. Does this exist?

Comment: Would `pip` be a good solution for you? A `pip install --upgrade` will always give you the latest version.

Comment: There is the option of using `pip download pydy`. However, it will not always work; for example `pip download psycopg2` will fail [if you do not also have PostgreSQL installed](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/712) due to pip trying to run some of the hooks in setup.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pypi provides no such links. Releases can have multiple download files (binaries for different Python versions, different distribution formats, etc), and that set of downloadable files can differ from version to version.

Use a decent installer tool (such as `pip`) and have it query pypi for you, then determine what is the latest version and what to best download for that version, instead.

For example, `pip install -U` will install the latest version for you, or upgrade an already installed version to the latest.

For a project page, just link to the PyPI page without a version:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydy
```

and visitors are shown the currently visible release. Unless you state otherwise, old releases are automatically hidden when you add a new release.

Comment: My use case is simply to have a "Latest Source Release" link on my project website that I don't have to manually update every time I make a release. This answers the question, i.e. "Does it exist?"

Comment: @moorepants: just link to the top-level pypi page for your project; it'll link to the lastest release with the downloads.