# How to get latest sdist link from PyPI

Tags: python, pypi

I want to get sdist url for meta.yaml in conda build recipe. It needs to get a specific version or latest version from URL. as I do it using Github actions for CI/CD I need to retrieve a source link of either specific version or the latest version automatically.

Now the link is like this: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/e7/sha-256-of-file/file I need something reliable like https://hosting/package/release/file

I need to know a more reliable way to retrieve either the latest sdist or sdist of a specific release. Is there any way to do that or I need to go another way?

[Is there a PyPi source download link that always points to the lastest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701312/is-there-a-pypi-source-download-link-that-always-points-to-the-lastest-version)

This question doesn't work for me by far as I don't seek to install it in python. I need that to include it in meta.yaml recipe for conda-build.

meta.yaml looks like this:

```
{% set version = "0.1.1rc3" %}

package:
  name: blablablah
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  url: 
  sha256: f3832918bc3c66617f92e35f5d70729187676313caa60c187eb0f28b8fe5e3b5

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 0
  script: python -m pip install --no-deps --ignore-installed .

requirements:
  host:
    - python
    - pip
    - numpy==1.16.5
    - cython
  run:
    - python

test:
  imports:
    - blablablah

about:
   here are information about the package
```

I don't know where to get this file as code updates hourly and manual upgrade is not possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a PyPi source download link that always points to the lastest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701312/is-there-a-pypi-source-download-link-that-always-points-to-the-lastest-version)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. I am not searching for installing using pip. I search a sdist file to use it in conda-build specifically and it is not intended for installing using pip.

Comment: Well, it does. Because the answer is "no", and you have to accept that. Sometimes "no way" is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact project name and version, you can use the following URL structure:

```py
project_name = "..."
version = "..."
url = f"https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/{project_name[0]}/{project_name}/{project_name}-{version}.tar.gz
```

e.g.

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-20.0.1.tar.gz

If you don't know the latest version, you can use the [PyPI JSON API](https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/json/) to get it:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> resp = requests.get('https://pypi.org/pypi/pip/json').json()
>>> resp['info']['version']
'20.0.1'
```

**Note:** there is no guarantee that a source distribution for a given version exists, although it is likely.